# Google Map when loaded comes over everything

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, razor

First in my Razor view I had a table containing data and below it a google map. But then I decided to put the google map above the table. When the page loads I can see the table for about half a second than it disappears and the google map takes its place. How can I fix this? to load the map I used this :

```
<div style="height:500px; width:1000px;" id="map-canvas" />
```

and above it I put the javascript for the map

After this  there is the table element.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Move the table code below the map code and that should fix the issue